# Bloquear o scroll do mouse em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, polymer

Fiz um programa usando *polymer* e dentro de um dos componentes em uma área específica (a área da legenda do meu gráfico) quero que o scroll da página não funcione, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode ocultar o `scroll` quando o mouse passar em uma determinada área, no meu exemplo eu coloquei para ocultar o `overflow` ao passar pela `<div id="azul">`.

```js
var azul = document.getElementById("azul");

azul.onmouseover = function(){
   document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
};

azul.onmouseout = function(){
   document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
};
```

```css
#total{
  height: 900px;
}

#amarela{
  background-color: yellow;
  height:50%;
}

#azul{
  background-color: blue;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="total">
  <div id="amarela"></div>
  <div id="azul"></div>
</div>
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915882/disabling-mouse-scrolling

Comment: então Caique, eu tinha visto algumas respostas para perguntas similares da forma como voce falou, mas ao executar esse é o retorno que tenho: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", acho que eh devido a estar usando o polymer, o que faz eu estar operando em shadow dom

Comment: Esse erro é porque a solução que postei utiliza a biblioteca Jquery e ela precisa ser incluida para poder funcionar: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, assim ela não depende mais do `jquery` veja se te ajuda ;)